# Local Variable Type Inference

Tags: java

I've been learning Java for 4 weeks. I use Notepad++ to write code and Command Prompt to compile and run Java files. Whenever I use var as local variable type inference, I always get the following error in the Command Prompt: Cannot find symbol.

```
class VarDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        var avg = 10.0;
        System.out.println("Value of avg: " + avg);

 }
```

Comment: What version of Java are you running?

Comment: The var keyword was added in Java 10. If you run "java -version" it will probably show a java version below 10, which would cause this issue.

Comment: I use this version: 
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are running a recent Java version.

You can install the latest long term support version Java 11 with [OpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)  and uninstall your older version.

`var` was introduced in Java 10. You can't use it if you have an older JDK.

If you want to stick with Java 8, you can't use local variable type inference, and you will have to change that line to:

`double avg = 10.0;`

Answer (score 2):

Creating a variable with `var` isnt' available in Java until the Java 10 version.

You should check your Java version and if you have a lower than Java 10 declare the variable with other type like this:

```
class VarDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double avg = 10.0;
        System.out.println("Value of avg: " + avg);

 }
```

For more info about `var` in Java 10: https://developer.oracle.com/java/jdk-10-local-variable-type-inference

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `Java` version, use `double` or `float` instead.